# Do Plucker relation follow from a subsystem of equations?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

The following system of equation: $i, j \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}$, $i+1<j$, $J \subset \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}$, $J \cap \{i,j,i+1,j+1\} = \emptyset$,
\begin{align*}
P_{i,j,J}P_{i+1,j+1,J} = P_{i,j+1,J} P_{i+1,j,J} + P_{i,i+1,J}P_{j,j+1,J}. \quad (1)
\end{align*}
is a subsystem of the system of Plucker relations: $i,j,k,l \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}$, $J \subset \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}$, $J \cap \{i,j,k,l\}=\emptyset$, $i<j<l<k$,
\begin{align*}
P_{i,k,J}P_{j,l,J} = P_{i,l,J} P_{j,k,J} + P_{i,j,J}P_{k,l,J}. \quad (2)
\end{align*}

Do the equations in (2) follow from the equation in (1)? Thank you very much.

Edit: division by positive integers is allowed, division by P's is allowed, division by polynomials of P's is allowed.

Comment: "Follow" in what way? Is division by positive integers allowed? Is division by $P$'s allowed? By other polynomials?

Comment: @darij grinberg, thank you very much. Yes, division by positive integers is allowed, division by P's is allowed, division by polynomials is allowed. I will edit the question.

Comment: How do we tell which polynomials we can divide by? (Obviously not by ones that are in the ideal generated by the Plücker relations...)